# How can I safely swap the ids of two rows that are references in other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So let's say I have a table like

```
   Table 1 
=============
id | ... 
=============
 1 | ... 
 2 | ... 
 3 | ...
 .    .
 .    .
 .    .

       Table 2 
=======================
id | table1_id | ... 
=======================
 1 |     1     | ... 
 2 |     1     | ... 
 3 |     2     | ... 
 .       .        .
 .       .        . 
 .       .        .
```

where `table1_id` in `Table 2` references `id` in `Table 1`.

I want to the `id`s of the rows with `id=1` and `id=2`.

Can I do this without screwing up the relationships?

Comment: Is flopping the fk (table1_id) an option because that is easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a dummy entry with copy of id 1 row in [Table 1] with new id. Then update all columns of id 1 with id 2 with following query

```
UPDATE  T
SET T.col2  = S.col2
    ,T.col3 = S.col3
    ,T.col4 = S.col4
    .     = .
    .     = .
    .     = .
[Table 1] T
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT col2
            ,col3
            ,col4
            .
            .
         FROM [Table 1]
         WHERE id = 2
        ) S
WHERE id = 1
```

In this same way update all columns of row id 2 with newly created row. After this delete newly created row.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary entry with a new id in Table 1, move the references in Table 2 from `table1_id=1` to the new id, move `table1_id=2` to `table_1_id=1` and then move the temporary referencves to `table1_id=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy row to table1.

Update table2 : `update table2 set table1-id = dummyid where table1-id = 1` .

Then: `update table2 set table1-id = 1 where table1-id = 2`.

Lastly: `update table2 set table1-id = 2 where table1-id = dummyid`.

You can use this logic to change table1 also.